# meta-telephony ERROR: oe_runmake failed

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Whenever I add meta-telephony to poky(meta-raspberrypi) and tried to execute 'bitbake askterik'
 I am getting the following error.I am new to yocto please help me.
[image: This is the error I am getting]

Comment: Did you add the meta-telephony with the same branch as the others?

Comment: I can't find any 9e50db commit for meta-telephony, please use the latest commit [here](https://github.com/ctrob67/meta-telephony/commit/22e8c8129f250ffbf58c3e8b33728688cda29814)